# Do you need to import a module into a module if it isn't used in the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was wondering, if I have a component in `Module2`, and I use the component in `Module1`, do I need to import `Module2` into `Module1` if it is only going to be used in the typescript and not the template, for example as a `@ContentChild(Component2) component2` like in the example below (**Note**: each module is a secondary entry point if that matters).

By removing it from the `imports` list, the application builds and runs, but is it bad practice?

This uses the directive from `Module2` in the typescript but not the template:

```
import { Directive2, Module2 } from '@org/library/module-2';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl" />`,
})
export class Component1 {
  @ContentChild(Directive2, { read: TemplateRef })
  tpl: TemplateRef<unknown> | null = null;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, Module2], // Is Module2 even needed as it's not used in the template
  exports: [Component1],
  declarations: [Component1],
})
export class Module1 {}
```

Example dependency for `Module1`.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
})
export class Directive2 {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Directive2],
  exports: [Directive2],
})
export class Module2 {}
```

Within the Application (imports both `Module1` and `Module2` in `AppModule`):

```
import { Module1 } from '@org/library/module-1';
import { Module2 } from '@org/library/module-2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, Module1, Module2],
  template: `
    <example>
      <ng-template my-directive>
        Hello World
      </ng-template>
    </example>
  `,
})
export class App {}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module are a way to scope components/directives.

You are required to import a Module when one of the declared component/directive is directly used in the template.

So no you don't need to import `Module2` in `Module1` as `Directive2` isn't used in the template itself.